# Accessibility order IOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uiaccessibility

I have a *UICollectionviewController* in which I set a *contentInset* to add a *ProfileView* to the top of *collectionView*, the reason why we do that is we already have a *headerView* and we want this *profileView* to act much different from the header of the collectionView.

But at this point the order of my Accessibility Items is messed up, for example the *profileView* is called first, but when I swipe left it goes to the bottom of the *collectionView*.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: is this issue solved ?

Comment: Hey @Mr.T, no I haven't found a solution to this yet.

Comment: are you changing the accessibility elemetns anywhere in your code ?

Comment: you need to add the elements in the order you want to an accessible elements array, so that it will be called in the order you add the elemetns

Comment: what do you mean changing the accessibility elements?

Comment: so since, its a view controller I can't exactly intercept any of the accessibility methods, I can only intercept them if I was subclassing a UIView.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the order of accessibility elements by modifying the accessibility array.

Let's say your array looks like this:

```
   self.view.accessibilityElements=@[firstElement,secondElement];
```

In this case, voice over read first element and then after you swipe , focus goes to second element.

Please note that voice over can only work on left to right and from top to bottom, you cant move the focus other than these two directions.

Comment: This didn't do much to my view controller, also I want my collectionView cells to be accessibility elements too, I can't exactly add the cell to this array.

Comment: `.view` is the important part for me, odd that ViewControllers support it but doesn't do anything at all